# How to host a fossil repository with lighttpd?

Tags: lighttpd, scm

I have a fossil project and want to host it in a server of mine. I'm using lighttpd to serve the git interface for some other projects so using apache or nginx is out of the question.

I have followed the -rather simple- [instructions](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/webui.wiki) and given read, write and execute permissions to `www-data` in both the cgi-script and the repository.

The relevant part of my lighttpd.conf looks like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^fossil-project.my-server.com$" {
server.groupname           = "www-data"
server.username            = "www-data"
cgi.assign = (
   ".cgi" => "/usr/bin/fossil"
)
alias.url += (
  "/" => "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/fossilweb.cgi"
)
}
```

Going to my project in a web browser confirms that the cgi script works well, as it is redirecting from `/` to `/index`, the default landing page for the fossil web interface, but, instead of showing the project page (which also works, as confirmed by running `fossil ui fossil-project.fossil`) it spits out a `404`!

I guess I'm missing something in the host configuration in the `lighttpd.conf` that tells it 
that all urls under `/` in that subdomain should be handled by `fossil` instead of by lighttpd, but I don't know how to do *that*

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have two choices:

1. Use fossil server and then proxy the requests from lighttpd to fossil via mod_proxy
2. Use fossil's built in CGI see http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/wiki?name=Cookbook#CGI.

You might get some hints from mercurial's and/or trac's way of setting things up.

Comment: Thanks man! I ended up using xinetd for serving up the repo and using mod_proxy like you suggested for redirecting requests from my subdomain to the port where xinetd is listening; worked like a charm :)